# Best way to query model relationship in Eloquent

Tags: laravel

I am working within a controller in a Laravel application.  I am returning a table to the view.  The table is based on my PlanSubmission model.  I am receiving parameters through a GET request and using those parameters to return a filtered set of rows to my view.

The first part of my controller looks like this and is working fine:

```php
public function index()
    {

    //Used for filter.  The request is received in the URL
    if (request()->has('status')) {
        $plans = PlanSubmission::where('status', request('status'))->paginate(25)->appends('status', request('status'));
    }
    elseif (request('employer_name')) {
        $plans = PlanSubmission::where('employer_name', request('employer_name'))->paginate(25)->appends('employer_name', request('employer_name'));
        }
```

I have run into a problem because now I need to use a model relationship in the controller.  I am receiving 'advisor_name' from the request.  The 'advisor_id" column is the foreign key on the PlanSubmission model.  The 'advisor_name' column exists in the Advisor model.  I have a function on my PlanSubmission model that looks like this:

```
    public function advisor()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Advisor::class);
}
```

Initially, I thought there was a way I could do this easily with something like:

```
            $plans = PlanSubmission::where(advisor->name, request('advisor_name'))->paginate(25)->appends('advisor_name', request('advisor_name'));
```

Of course, this will not work because I cannot enter a relationship into the first parameter in the Where Clause.

I do not know where to go from here.  My other thought is to return all the advisors first from the Advisor model like this:

```
            $advisors = Advisor::where('name', request('advisor_name'));
```

Then, I imagine I would have to somehow loop through that and get the id (primary key) for each of the objects in $advisors and somehow get that into the PlanSubmission where clause.  I'm totally lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Victor mentions in his answer you can use [`whereHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) like so:

```php
PlanSubmission::whereHas('advisor', function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', request('advisor_name'));
});
```

You didn't asked this directly, but I noticed that you use conditionals to make different queries. Eloquent provides a few way to make this a bit nicer to deal with.

The first which is kind of obvious is that that whatever method you call a builder (query) is returned that you can just add on to. It could be there were some common restrictions in your two cases:

```php
public function index()
{
   $query = PlanSubmission::where('something', 42);
   
   if (request()->has('status')) {
       $query = $query->where('status', request('status'));
   } elseif (..) {
     ...
   }

   return $query->paginate(25);
}
```

Another way to do conditional queries in Laravel is using [`when`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#conditional-clauses). E.g. for status:

```php
$query = $query->when(request->has('status'), function ($query) {
    // note that you don't have to return the query
    $query->where('status', request('status'));
});

// or PlanSubmission::>when(..)
```

In your example you cannot both filter by `status` AND `advisor_name`, but lets assume that would be okay, then you can combine everything like so:

```php
public function index()
{
   return PlanSubmission::query()
       //->where('something', 42)
       ->when(request->has('status'), function ($query) {
           $query->where('status', request('status'));
       })
       ->when(request->has('advisor_name'), function ($query) {
           $query->whereHas('advisor', function ($query) {
               $query->where('name', request('advisor_name'));
           });
       })->paginate(25);
}
```

This approach may seem verbose for simple queries and then it is fine to use `if` conditions, but for complex queries `when` can be useful. Also the idea of "building up a query" also works nice in those situation. You can pass the query builder around and continuously build it up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `whereHas` for that

[docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence)